# NSManagedObject Custom Class --NSInvalidArgumentException unrecognized selector --

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a custom NSManagedObject Class That Looks Like This.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Ingredient, MenuCategory, Price, ItemSize;

@interface Item : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * collected;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * desc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * instructions;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * quantity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * selected;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MenuCategory *menuCategory;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *prices;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *itemSizes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *itemIngredients;


-(NSMutableSet *)mutablePrices;
-(NSMutableSet *)mutableItemIngredients;

@end

#import "Item.h"
#import "Ingredient.h"
#import "MenuCategory.h"
#import "Price.h"
#import "ItemSize.h"


@implementation Item

@dynamic collected;
@dynamic desc;
@dynamic instructions;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic quantity;
@dynamic selected;
@dynamic itemIngredients;
@dynamic menuCategory;
@dynamic prices;
@dynamic itemSizes;


-(NSMutableSet *)mutablePrices{

    return [self mutableSetValueForKey:@"prices"];
}

-(NSMutableSet *)mutableItemIngredients{

    return [self mutableSetValueForKey:@"itemIngredients"];
}

@end
```

Nothing so special RIGHT ??? 
The Following Should Work Right ????

```
[item.mutablePrices addObject:newPrice]
```

BUT IT DOES NOT GIVES ME THE FOLLOWING ERROR

```
2014-03-30 10:25:34.594 restos[1192:60b] -[NSManagedObject mutablePrices]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe8d72c0
2014-03-30 10:25:34.597 restos[1192:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject mutablePrices]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe8d72c0'
```

BUT WHEN I DO THE FOLLOWING

```
[[item mutableSetValueForKey:@"prices"] addObject:newPrice];
```

WORKS JUST FINE --- I KNOW IS SOMETHING SIMPLE FOR SOME REASON I CAN NOT SEE IT ----

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

```
-[NSManagedObject mutablePrices]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe8d72c0
```

indicates that your `item` object is not an instance of the `Item` class. A possible reason could be that you did not set the *class* of the entity to "Item" in the Core Data 
model inspector.

Generally it is less error prone if you let Xcode generate the NSManagedObject subclass files (from the Edit menu), and add your custom methods in a Class Category. Alternatively, use ["mogenerator"](http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/).